# Android: GPS in web-browser

Tags: java, android, gps

I am making a web-browser.
There is I have written in the Android Manifest of my app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Users without GPS cannot install my app.

But there is Dolphin Browser have this code in Manifest too, but users without GPS can install Dolphin Browser.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the manifest add a tag

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
```

This lets devices without a GPS install the app

You can read more at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html